# Angular routing: 404 not found on webserver

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I try to approach an exact url like: 'angularwebsite.com/thispage' by myself. Locally this works. When I try the same thing on the webserver with the exact same angular (build) project, it does not. A 404 page pops up.

Does anybody know what this is caused by and/or how I can solve this?

**EDIT:** I found that routing is working on a project of someone else where routing is added differently. In this project '/#/' has to be included between the specific page and the url of the webserver. Like 'angularwebsite.com/#/thispage

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I can set 'useHash' to true the moment I import all of the approutes. This makes it work on the webserver:

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true } )
```